# `pip install -e .` does not work in windows conda environment

Tags: windows, conda

I want to install a local package. Usually, I would go to the package directory and type

```
pip install -e .
```

And then be able to use the package from anywhere, if the respective **conda** environment is activated. Though under Windows I get the message

> Successfully installed {package}

But if I try to import it, I get

> Module not found

How can I properly install a local package in a **conda** environment under Windows?

Answer (score 3):

Did you

```
conda install pip
```

?  A conda environment needs it's own pip, then

```
pip install -e path/to/a/python/package
```

works.

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: That was Ubuntu 18.10.

Comment: Oops, sorry, didn't see that you had specified Windows!

Comment: Exactly the same thing works under Windows 10, here using Anaconda Navigator 1.9.7 and Python 3.7.3.

Comment: It does not work on my system. But good to know, that it should work.

Answer (score 0):

On the output from this command line

```
pip install -e .
```

It might warn you that the package has been installed locally.
Thus, modifying the `PATH` variable would help.